# How to build this view for n number of removable cards?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-layout

Which widget would be best to use? If listview.builder then can you please share a sample code? [This is the UI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FTl6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GridView` is the widget you're looking for. Just use `GridView.count` will give you the desired result

Implementation of `GridView.count()`

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(10, (index) => const DemoCard()));
  }
```

And here the full example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: List.generate(10, (index) => const DemoCard()));
  }
}

class DemoCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const DemoCard({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      child: Card(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
        elevation: 10,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.developer_mode,
                color: Colors.blue,
                size: 50,
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                'Demo Text',
                style: Theme.of(context)
                    .textTheme
                    .titleMedium!
                    .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 2),
              Text(
                'Sub-Demo Text',
                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium!.copyWith(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.lightBlue),
              ),
              const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: TextButton(
                        child: const Text('Edit Privilage'),
                        onPressed: () {},
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The result would be:

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it in two ways:

- [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) Widget
- [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) Package